# How to set the expect calling counts for void method when using EasyMock + PowerMock?

Tags: java, easymock, powermock

```
File mockFile = createMockAndExpectNew(File.class, fileParentPath+fileName);
RandomAccessFile mockRandomAccessFile = createMockAndExpectNew(RandomAccessFile.class, mockFile, "rw");
mockRandomAccessFile.seek(0L);
```

I want to set invocation counts for this expected void method, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

To expect the last call 3 times, you can use the [`expectLastCall`](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#expectLastCall%28%29) method:

```
// mockRandomAccessFile is a mock
mockRandomAccessFile.seek(0L);
EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(3);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I failed:
  'mockRandomAccessFile.seek(0L);
  EasyMock.expectLastCall.times(0);'
And I got this:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maximum must be >= 1

Comment: You have to use strick mocks, don't expect this method call and verify the mock at the end of the execution. This question explains in details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710717/test-that-void-method-didnt-get-called-with-easymock